# PHP Regex : How to limit only start capturing until (and including) a matching line?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to read in a file in php and capture an array of matches.  I have a pattern that works for what I want, but only if I begin the matching after a certain point in the file - after that is fine.

I'm reading in a .less file that looks like this:

```
/* ... */

.icon-flip-vertical:before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, -1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1, -1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1, -1);
  -o-transform: scale(1, -1);
  transform: scale(1, -1);
}
/* ensure rotation occurs inside anchor tags */
a .icon-rotate-90:before,
a .icon-rotate-180:before,
a .icon-rotate-270:before,
a .icon-flip-horizontal:before,
a .icon-flip-vertical:before {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* start capturing with pattern here */

.icon-glass:before{content:"\f000";}
.icon-music:before{content:"\f001";}
.icon-search:before{content:"\f002";}
.icon-envelope-alt:before{content:"\f003";}

/* ... more like this after */
```

I'm trying to capture the "meat" of the icon-classes.  ie: `.icon-XXXX:before`
I'm using the pattern `\.icon-([^:]+)` successfully, but like I said, I want to begin matching  at the specified point in the file.

One important note is that for some reason, not all icon classes are on their own line.

I'm thinking if I could set the matching to begin on the line that contains the string `\f000` that would do the trick. How to do that, I have yet to find.

Thanks in advance to all for their time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before applying your regex matching, extract the piece of string you wanna work on:

```
$subString = substr($string,strpos($string,"start capturing with pattern here"));
```

Then, apply your regex on that substring.

Please note that for using this approach, you must pick a separator (in my example, `start capturing with pattern here`) that breaks the string in two pieces: a useless one and the useful one.

Comment: This is just what I was thinking shortly after I asked this question.  I started with the regex in sublime so I wasn't thinking about how to approach it in php..

I'll mark this as the answer.  My solution ended up using `$start      = strpos( $source, '.icon-glass:before');` rather than requiring it's own special string for this - although I thought about that too.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using a lookahead assertion.  Something like:

```
(?<=\.icon-)[\w-]+(?=:before[^\w-][^}]*?"\\\\f00)
```

should match exactly the word following `.icon-`, but only if that word is also followed by `:before` and a block containing `"\f00`.

Note, this assumes your CSS doesn't have syntax errors (in particular, that there aren't unclosed blocks). If it does, a regex probably won't be able to handle it.